# how to display an image from a button angular 4

Tags: html, angular, typescript

So I'm trying to make a basic website and I need to display an image when I click on a button. The problem is that it displays me the image but when I click on another button to diplay me an another image the precedent image stays.
here is my code. I'm using Angular 4 and typescript.

component.ts

```
openPredictionImg() {
const myImg = new Image();
myImg.useMap = '../../assets/prediction.png';
const img = document.createElement('img');
document.body.appendChild(img);
img.setAttribute('src', myImg.useMap);
img.onload = (stop);}

openRebalancingImg() {
const myImg = new Image();
myImg.useMap = '../../assets/rebalancing.png';
const img = document.createElement('img');
document.body.appendChild(img);
img.setAttribute('src', myImg.useMap);
img.onload = (stop);}

openVisualizationImg() {
const myImg = new Image();
myImg.useMap = '../../assets/visualization.png';
const img = document.createElement('img');
document.body.appendChild(img);
img.setAttribute('src', myImg.useMap);
img.onload = (stop);}
```

component.html

```
<button class="predictionBtn "(click)="openPredictionImg()" style="width: 10%">Prediction</button>

<button class="rebalancingBtn" (click)="openRebalancingImg()" style="width: 10%">Rebalancing</button>

<button class="visualizationBtn" (click)="openVisualizationImg()" style="width: 10%">Visualization</button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok here is the solution

component.ts

```
text = '';
openPrediction() {
this.text = '...' }
```

component.html

```
<button class="predictionBtn " (click)="imageSource = '../../assets/prediction.png'; openPrediction()" >Prediction</button>
<img [src]="imageSource" *ngIf="imageSource" style="width: 10%"/>
{{ text }}
```

Answer (score 1):

In Angular, you don't touch the DOM directly.

The simplest way I can think of :

```
<button class="predictionBtn "(click)="imageSource = '../../assets/prediction.png'" style="width: 10%">Prediction</button>

<button class="rebalancingBtn" (click)="imageSource = '../../assets/rebalancing.png'" style="width: 10%">Rebalancing</button>

<button class="visualizationBtn" (click)="imageSource = '../../assets/visualization.png'" style="width: 10%">Visualization</button>

<img [src]="imageSource" *ngIf="imageSource"/>
```

In your Typescript, remove all of your previous code and simply declare a variable

```
imageSource: string;
```

Comment: Thank you very much
I have another question

Comment: How can I add a text and an image to a button

Comment: And I've tried your code but it doesn't display's me the image

Comment: A button is just a tag, do it like you would add it in a div.

Comment: And **[it works for me](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bmkqt7?file=app%2Fapp.component.html)** so you probably did something else.

Comment: It works but I can't display the image and the text simultaneously

Comment: There's no text in your question.